# Dúvida sobre o tipo de permissão ao se criar pasta e arquivo com os.Mkdir() e os.OpenFile()

Tags: linux, golang, file-permission

Gente, em um determinado momento no meu código eu estou criando uma pasta (1) na qual serão arquivadas fotos postadas por usuários e um arquivo CSV (2) no qual serão arquivados os metadados dessas imagens. Estou pensando aqui a respeito das permissões.

Até agora estou usando as permissões 666, mas acho que isso representaria uma vulnerabilidade, não é verdade? Facilitaria a vida de algum usuário mal intencionado que quisesse deletar tanto o arquivo quanto a pasta.

No meu caso específico, tanto as fotos quanto os outros dados serão apenas armazenados e não serão utilizados novamente (Estou apenas praticando aqui e me veio essa dúvida). Nesse caso 600 bastaria? Isso garantiria que o privilégio de criar e deletar pastas/arquivos ficaria reservado ao root?

E no caso de um sistema em que essas fotos, depois de armazenadas, fossem carregadas de acordo com o usuário, quais permissões usar? 644? Não é o caso ainda, mas se fosse um sistema que de fato fosse rodar em produção, eu não saberia o que fazer em cada um desses cenários. Alguma sugestão?

```
(1) os.Mkdir(foldername, 0666)

(2) metadataFile, err := os.OpenFile("metadata.csv", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos simplificar utilizando somente os 3 últimos valores {666}.

você aplicou *{para o usuário:6, para o grupo: 6, e para outros:6}*

o que significa cada número:

- 0 = nenhuma permissão;
- 1 = apenas executar;
- 2 = apenas gravar;
- 3 = gravar e executar;
- 4 = apenas ler;
- 5 = ler e executar;
- 6 = ler e gravar;
- 7 = ler, gravar e executar.

De forma mais resumida possível...

USUÁRIO é o dono: com 6 pode ler e modificar

Digamos que temos o grupo MACACOS-PREGOS, todos os membros desse grupo com 6, também pode ler e modificar os dados (pasta, arquivo), se eu querer apresentar e não permitir que alterem, devo então definir o valor 4.

OUTROS é o tal do "arquivo, pasta" público, deixar 6... vixe, vai permitir qualquer um modificar o arquivo ou pasta.

vamos praticar?

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.OpenFile("ninguem_mexe.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0444)
    file.WriteString("O rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma.")
}
```

Tente com um editor de texto  modificar o arquivo "ninguem_mexe.txt" e gravar.

**obs:** não vale a cópia.